# hibernate count distinct values

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I try to do something like

```
SELECT count(*) from (select distinct(col1, col2) from table);
```

using hibernate and mysql.

I know that I can't use subqueries in FROM clause.
Is there any way except `query.list().size()` or native sql?

Thanks

Comment: That's a limitation of hibernate?

Comment: Yes
[Source](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-subqueries)

Comment: Why do you want not to use nativ sql?

Comment: I don't want to have dependency from database